# Need to run npm update multiple times

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it normal to have to run `npm update` multiple times before all packages are fully updated? I ran it once and when I start node, it crashed. And then I ran `npm outdated` and noticed some packages are still not updated. I had to run `npm update` again twice before all packages are up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be happening—perhaps your version of npm is corrupted or outdated. If you're using Homebrew, you can run (in the command line) `brew update`, then `brew remove npm`, then `brew install npm` to reinstall everything. Hopefully that will get everything back up and running!

Comment: By the way, anyone know if there is a "reinstall" function in brew?